# Is it valid to have a form tag inside a table tag?

Tags: html

Is it **valid** to have a form tag inside a table tag? Some documentation links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`<form>` is valid inside a `<td>` element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-td-element).  You can check this sort of thing at http://validator.w3.org.  Choose "Validate by direct input", then paste the following HTML:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><form action="test"><div><input type="text"></div></form></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Under "More options", select "Validate document fragment".  This allows you to check a HTML snippet without writing an entire page for it.  I use it for checking HTML fragments all the time.

#### References:

- [The TD element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-td-element)
- [The FORM element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-form-element)

Answer (score 2):

Putting a `form` tag inside a `table` (but outside the rows) was sometimes used to keep the margins of the form to interfere with the layout. It kind of works, but it's invalid code according to the HTML standard.

Use CSS to remove the margin from the `form` tag instead. Example:

```
<form ... style="margin:0">
```

Or preferrably put it in your style sheet.

Comment: Older browsers allowed this but modern browsers are more strict about it. I just had a problem that was fixed by putting the table inside the form. The original form crossed <tr> boundaries.

Comment: @BrettSlocum: Yes, having the form directly in the table element causes less problems. If possible, place the form either surrounding the entire table or inside a table cell. Also, consider not using a table at all, you can do so much with CSS these days.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not restructuring my whole table for a simple "put the form outside the table" fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest a form within a td, its usually fine for most purposes though to wrap a form around a table

Answer (score 0):

It is valid to put a `<form>` tag inside a `<table>` tag.

```
<table>
   <tr>
   <td>
   <form name="sample" action="test.php">
<div>
   <input type="submit" value="submit" >
</div>
   </form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

*Editing note: tags wrapped as code so that the content reads as intended, but the answer should specify that while the form is inside the table, it cannot be a direct descendant: it must be a child of a cell.*

Comment: Inside a TD tag, but don't cross TD boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="#">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>list</th>
                <th>button</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" required="required"></td>
                <td><button type="submit" id="saveRow">Save me</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>


    </table>

</form>
```