# Form tag won't enclose elements inside a table

Tags: html, forms, html-table, semantics

I've run into a curious problem; I've got a form inside a `<tr>`, however the form refuses to wrap any tags inside it. I've made a quick JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/rrPqM/) to play around with. Firebug reports that the form isn't wrapping anything:

[image]

The `<form>` element is greyed out and not wrapping anything. The HTML for this test is below

```
<table>
    <form>
        <tr>
            <td>Input</td>
            <td>Another input</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><span>Other stuff</span></td>
        </tr>
    </form>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Rows not affected by the form
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Rows not affected by the form
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As can be seen, the `form` holds two `tr`s in the written markup. [I read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622405/is-it-valid-to-have-a-form-tag-inside-a-table-tag) that this is invalid, so my question is **can I create a form that holds two or more `tr`s and an arbitrary amount of other elements inside a table?** The table has other rows in it not associated with the form, so putting a `<form>` round the entire table is unhelpful, although seeing as the other rows won't have any inputs for the form (POST request), I suppose a `form` could be put around the entire table.

Which is a better solution; whole-table wrap, or a working fix for just enclosing the needed rows in a `form` tag? I know I could put a `table` inside a `td > form`, but then the column widths wouldn't be the same in the nested table, which is why I came to ask this question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot interrupt the `<table>` structure with any tags besides `<thead>`, `<tfoot>`, `<tbody>`, `<tr>`, `<th>`, or `<td>`. You form tags need to be encapsulated between two `<td>` or your entire `<table>` needs to be placed within the `<form>` tag.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form>
            ...form data...
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

..or..

```
<form>
    <table>
    ...
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Micheal. Outside it is :-)

Answer (score 3):

you can only put a form inside a td basically, so you could put those 2 rows inside a new table that you create inside a td
like ...

```
<table><tr><td><form><table><tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr></table></form></td></tr><tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr></table>
```

Comment: Thanks Rodolfo. I've edited my question to reflect what I want; using a nested table isn't possible due to the fact I need to preserve column widths.

Comment: if the other rows don't have any input fields that belong to another form then just put the whole table inside the form

Comment: I think this is the general consensus to have `<form>` outside `<table>`, which is what I'll do. It was a bit obvious, but I wanted to know if there was a more semantic option of only wrapping what was a form in `<form>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

The `<form>` tag can only be placed inside a `<td>` element or outside the `<table>` in this case.

If I were you, I'd just put the `<form>` around the whole table since you said there won't be any other forms within it.

Or, you could replace the `<table>` completely with `<div>`s instead that use `display: table;` or `display: table-cell;`.

Comment: The only problem I can see with the `<div>` structure is that `table-cell` isn't very well supported. I think the general consensus is that putting `<form>` outside the table is the best way to go.

Comment: another apparent issue with `<div style="table-cell">` is that if you are dynamically replacing a row in the table through an ajax call, the columns don't align properly, or at least I couldn't get it to work; love to hear from someone who has though!