# Why do form element can not be child of table,tr,td?

Tags: html, forms

I was in situation where i need to use forms in a table row, but surprisingly I could see  that form element can not be child of table,td,tr. Is there any logical reason for this restriction, or is there any work around for this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form tag won't enclose elements inside a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615903/form-tag-wont-enclose-elements-inside-a-table)

Comment: You can certainly contain your entire form within a table cell (`td`), and you can also have a `table` inside your form, but you cannot intermix the elements like this: `<table><form><tr> ... </tr></form></table>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be in a `td`, but a `table` should only contain `tr` (or `thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot`). `tr` should only contain `td`. So it's not the form element that cannot be in the table, it is the table that doesn't allow most elements, except some specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

A table-row (`tr`) must only contain table-data (`td`).

You can place your form in a `<td></td>` element.