# Selecting input by name inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to select the textarea inside of the td by the name. None of the normal methods seem to be working:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function () {
$( document ).on( 'click', 'button', function (event) {
    $(".myForm [name='name']").val('Hello World!');
    $(".myForm td [name='name']").val('Hello World!');
    $(".myForm td textarea [name='name']").val('Hello World!');
    $(".myForm textarea [name='name']").val('Hello World!');
});
});</script>


<table>
<tr>
    <form class="myForm">
        <td>
            <textarea name="name"></textarea>
        </td>
    </form>
</tr>
</table>

<button>click me</button>

        </td>
    </form>
</tr>
</table>
```

click me

Comment: Putting a `<form>` tag between a `<tr>` and a `<td>` is not valid and causes problems. [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dox5rjv1/).

Comment: See: [Which DOM elements can be child of tr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634715/which-dom-elements-can-be-child-of-tr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem in non-standard wrapping of form element inside table.
Check it out here [Form tag won't enclose elements inside a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615903/form-tag-wont-enclose-elements-inside-a-table) and space, as others have pointed out.
Possible solution would be to re-organize your markup.

Comment: Ah, that... kinda makes sense...? Not really, but at least I know what it isn't working. That's kinda squirrely though, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround your whole `table` with the `form` and remove the space between element and attribute selector, i.e. `textarea[name='name']`.

https://jsfiddle.net/jd7qp4ts/

Comment: While that does work, you shouldn't need to surround the entire thing should you? That doesn't make sense with the DOM.

Comment: @Robbie Well, you're at least not allowed to place it in a [`tr` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr).