# Why won't jQuery submit this form?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit

I am trying to submit a form with jQuery and I must be missing something small, because I can't get this to work, and from everything I see it should work fine.

What's wrong with this?

```
<table class="newrecord"><form id="editthis" action="page.php" method="post">       

    <tr><td class="left">Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="left">Company:</td><td><input type="text" name="company" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="left"><a href="?action=browse">Cancel</a></td><td><input type="button" name="submit" class="subbut" id="subthis" value="Update" /></td></tr>

</form></table>
```

And the javascript:

```
    $("#subthis").click(function() {
        $('#editthis').submit(); // An alert box works, so I know this is triggering
    });
```

As mentioned in the code, an alert box works if I click the submit button, but when I use the jQuery submit function, nothing happens. What am I missing???

Comment: Why would you need a form submit itself on document.ready? Edit: I didn't notice event binding. Must not read SO when exhausted. Lesson learnt

Comment: Have you tried putting the `form` tags *outside* the `table` tags so that you have valid HTML?  [This SO article might be related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622405/is-it-valid-to-have-a-form-tag-inside-a-table-tag)

Comment: @CengizCan - The form isn't submitting itself.  The code is attaching the `click` event when the document is ready.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two possible problems.

1) You have `form` tags inside `table` tags.  While this probably isn't the root cause of your problem, it's not valid HTML.

2) You've used "submit" as the `name` of your submit button. This should be avoided because your object will collide with JavaScript reserved words.  Use something other than "submit" like you've done with the `id` attribute.

Comment: I had moved the form inside table when I was troubleshooting. #2 was it though! I renamed the button and it works. Thank you!!!

Comment: Great!  Please be sure to accept the answer that is most appropriate for your solution.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize there's a timer on that.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use jQuery to submit a form. It's default behavior for a submit button to submit the form it belongs to.

Also, don't use a table for layout. The form elements themselves can layout just fine.

```
<form id="edit_this" action="page.php" method="POST">
    <label>Name <input type="text" name="name"></label>
    <label>Company <input type="text" name="company"></label>
    <a href="?action=browse">Cancel</a>
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

Can be easily layout'd and will submit on its own.

If you need something to happen before the submission with jQuery, bind it to the form's `onsubmit` handler, rather than the actual click of the button.

---

The actual problem is the collision between the name you've given to the button and the reserved word in JavaScript. Don't use `submit` as the name.

Comment: I know I don't need to, but I have some other stuff I want to do with this form using jquery, I've just got it down to barebones until I can fix this issue.