# No error shown when updating and deleting

Tags: php, html

I have those codes that help to update and delete a row from a table:

html:

```
<table class="imagetable" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="400px" border="1">
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Informations</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id'] ?>"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="med_name" value="<?php echo $rows['med_name'] ?>"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="info" value="<?php echo $rows['info']?>"/></td>
        <td>
            <form action="update_del.php" method="post">
                <input class="imgClass_update" type="submit" name="submit1" value="" />
                <input class="imgClass_dell" type="submit" name="submit2" value=""/>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
require_once('../include/global.php');
$id=$_POST['id'];
if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
    $name=$_POST['med_name'];
    $info=$_POST['info'];

    $sql = "UPDATE med SET med_name='$name', 
                            info='$info' 
                            WHERE id='$id'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($con)); 

    if($result){
        header("location:med.php"); 
    }
    else
    {
        header("location:update_false.php"); 

    }
}
if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
{
    $sql = "DELETE FROM med WHERE id='$id'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($con));
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 1)
    {
        header("location:med.php"); 
    }
    else
    {
        header("location:update_false.php"); 

    }
}
?>
```

Nothing is updated nor deleted. And no errors are shown. If someone could help me, I think the problem is too easy but can't see it where.

Comment: Well you prob won't see errors since you redirect before you can even see an error.. + you are not POSTING anything since your form only covers the submit buttons, and not the input fields you are looking for...

Comment: can you fix the code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are placing `<form>` tag at wrong place.

Therefore, your other elements: `id`, `med_name` and `info` are not children of `form`.

And they are not getting posted.

You should start `<form>` before table and end after table.

Corrected Code:

```
<form action="update_del.php" method="post">
<table class="imagetable" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="400px" border="1">
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Informations</th>
<th>Actions</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id'] ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="med_name" value="<?php echo $rows['med_name'] ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="info" value="<?php echo $rows['info']?>"/></td>
<td>
<input class="imgClass_update" type="submit" name="submit1" value="Update" />
<input class="imgClass_dell" type="submit" name="submit2" value="Delete"/>        
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: sir, I need to echo the id inside a td and use the id number to make the update. how to do that by echoing the id inside a td and get the value in action page ?

Comment: Yeah, and I want to get the id of the row to update t without showing in a TD with name tag. If you didnt get what I mean I can explain more

Comment: I need to get the id for each row without showing the id on the page

Answer (score 2):

just do this -

```
<table class="imagetable" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="400px" border="1">
<form action="update_del.php" method="post">
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Informations</th>
<th>Actions</th>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id'] ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="med_name" value="<?php echo $rows['med_name'] ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="info" value="<?php echo $rows['info']?>"/></td>
<td>

<input class="imgClass_update" type="submit" name="submit1" value="" />
<input class="imgClass_dell" type="submit" name="submit2" value=""/>

</td>
</tr> 
</form>
```

Comment: Form inside a table doesnt work i guess... Just cross check that.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju well form has nothing to do with table.... its just that values need to be submitted should be put inside the form...

Comment: @ManojSalvi can you explain ?

Comment: @NiranjanN Raju just see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622405/is-it-valid-to-have-a-form-tag-inside-a-table-tag

Comment: form inside td is ok, but form immediately after table will not work.

Comment: Just try running your answer once.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju i tried putting form inside table and its working fine getting the values, you should try once .....

Comment: Im telling you so many times because, i was stuck with this for more that 3 days. So...

Comment: Which ide do you use?/

Comment: i m using netbeans..... i know may be you would have stuck so just created a dummy form placed inside the table and took the values on other page its echoing values perfectly no errors...