# HTML tags get changed when assigning to innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I have an XML and i m transforming it to HTML using XSL. My transformation is successful and i am geting the resultant string like below :- `

```
<TABLE xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:xslscript="http://mycompany.com/mynamespace" border="0" width="100%">
   <TR align="center">
      <TD>
         <TABLE border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
            <FORM action="jhk" method="get" id="frmMain" name="frmMain">
               <TR>
                  <TD class="tableBg">
                     <TABLE border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" width="100%">
                        <TR class="mainListRow">
                           <TD colspan="7">
                              <TABLE width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                 <TR>
                                    <TD class="ListTableTitle" width="12%" nowrap="nowrap">Select Value                    </TD>
                                 </TR>
                              </TABLE>
                           </TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR width="100%">
                           <TD valign="top" width="100%">
                              <DIV id="listing" width="100%">
                                 <input type="hidden" id="keyField" value="partnerCd"/>
                                 <TABLE STYLE="background-color:white" id="tblList" border="0" bordercolor="#0099CC" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    </THEAD>
                                    <tr>
                                       <TD align="center" width="8px" height="10px"/>
                                       <TD colspan="1">
                                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                             <tr>
                                                <td><input type="text" class="text" name="searchFields" value=""/></td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </table>
                                       </TD>
                                       <TD colspan="1">
                                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                             <tr>
                                                <td/>
                                                <td align="right"><input type="button" class="buttonsNewCancelDeleteClose" id="buttonsSearchId" name="buttonsSearch" value="Search" onclick="searchPaginated()"/></td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </table>
                                       </TD>
                                    </tr>
                                 </TABLE>
                              </DIV>
                           </TD>
                        </TR>
                     </TABLE>
                  </TD>
               </TR>
               <TR>
                  <td>
                     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr class="tableFooter">
                           <td class="tableFooter" align="left" width="10%"/>
                           <TD class="tableFooter" id="tableFooter" width="90%" align="right"/>
                        </tr>
                     </table>
                  </td>
               </TR>
            </FORM>
         </TABLE>
      </TD>
   </TR>
</TABLE>
```

`

then i am assigning it to the innerHTML of Document..
but the form tag is closing in the same line after assignment. like below

```
<FORM action="jhk" method="get" id="frmMain" name="frmMain"></FORM>
```

Not able to understand why the tags are rallying.Can anyone please help .I am not able to find any missmatch.

thanks

Comment: If the HTML is not valid browsers can do odd things. Is the HTML valid? I have a feeling the `form` tag inside that `table` looks dodgy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it valid to have a form tag inside a table tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622405/is-it-valid-to-have-a-form-tag-inside-a-table-tag)

Comment: Thanks for the response , but the problem is the same way code works in IE. I am just having the problem while using in chrome.

Comment: When presenting a browser with invalid HTML all bets are off and each browser reacts differently and tries to adjust as best is it can. Instead of trying to focus on why it doesn't work in Chrome, first make sure your initial HTML is valid.

Answer (score 1):

A `<form>` can not be inside a `<table>`.

Either place it around the `<table>` or in a `<td>`

Comment: I will surely try this. But the strange thing for me is the same way it works in IE and not working in chrome. Although in IE the transformation is done with transformNode and with chrome i am using XSLTProcessor.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you have a stray `</THEAD>` tag on line 24 of your sample HTML.  This stray tag results in invalid markup, which could be causing the symptoms you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks ,this is my mistake , actually this was a big file and i removed some redundant tags to give the idea.